# Use a button to send info from one excel sheet to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I've got an excel spreadsheet that will collect data in the rows. I want to create a button that would send the cells from B3:I3 to a second sheet in the same workbook. After sending the data, the information from the first sheet should be deleted automatically.

I have the button created and the spreadsheet setup, but I have not used VBA in excel before and I'm having difficulty finding code to piece together to finish this sheet.

Can anyone provide some direction or help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3:I3").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:I3").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:I3").Clear
```